Bulk Archive Projects
Is there a way to archive a project through the API? I'd like to archive multiple projects at once that haven't been updated in the past year or two with a script or CURL request. Instead of doing this one one at a time on the admin web app.
I searched the API Ref doc but it looks we can only modify the Project image.

It is true what Geert Van Gorp has answered above.
The project archiving feature is only available on BIM 360. ACC is not supporting this feature currently.
A wish list has been logged for the engineering team to introduce the same on ACC to harmonize both cloud systems (BIM360 and ACC).
About bulk archiving, this is not supported too on BIM 360. you have to archive one project at a time using this API: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-PATCH/

Thanks Carol! That's a bummer but good to know it's not possible, yet

Also, is there a way to vote for this wish on the list you mentioned?

I have the same question. You can do it by API PATCH call for BIM 360. https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-:project_id-PATCH/
Unfortunately, I cannot find a similar PATCH call in the documentation for ACC.
The call is not forward compatible, according to Autodesk's documentation. https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/overview/bim-360-compatibility/compatibility-table/

Thanks for the info! Hopefully, someone else will have some insight too.

Update: I just received an answer from Autodesk:

Unfortunately, we do not have this PATCH project API as provided in BIM360. There is a wish that has been logged to provision this capability in ACC to maintain harmonization. The wish ticket is logged under: AECP-1013. Please may you reference this ticket ID in future follow up of the same. Kindly, we request your patience as I follow up on this ticket. I will revert soon as I get feedback regarding the same. Caroline Gitonga, Developer Advocate, Autodesk Platform Services (formerly Forge)

